# Add a certain word in multiple column names in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following df

```
date    place work home life friends university
23/01    Rio   4    10   5     5       10
24/02    LA    6    8    9     11      12
```

Desired df

```
date ind_place  ind_work ind_home ind_life ind_friends ind_university
23/01    Rio         4     10           5     5          10
24/02    LA          6      8           9     11         12
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign names to a subset of names(df)

```
names(df)[-1]<-paste0('ind_', names(df)[-1])
```

Or with dplyr, using `rename_with()`:

```
df%>%rename_with(~paste0("ind_", .x), .cols=-1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the code below

```
> cbind(df[1], setNames(df[-1], paste0("ind_", names(df)[-1])))
   date ind_place ind_work ind_home ind_life ind_friends ind_university
1 23/01       Rio        4       10        5           5             10
2 24/02        LA        6        8        9          11             12
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code adds the prefix "ind_" to all columns except the first one

```
col_names <- names(df)
names(df) <- c(col_names[1],
               paste0("ind_",col_names[2:length(col_names)]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `purrr::set_names()`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- read_table('date    place work home life friends university
23/01    Rio   4    10   5     5       10
24/02    LA    6    8    9     11      12')


df[-1] %>% 
    set_names(map_chr(names(.), ~str_c('ind_', .x))) %>%
    {cbind(df[1], .)}
#>    date ind_place ind_work ind_home ind_life ind_friends ind_university
#> 1 23/01       Rio        4       10        5           5             10
#> 2 24/02        LA        6        8        9          11             12

#better

df[-1] %>% 
    set_names(str_c('ind_', names(.))) %>%
    {cbind(df[1], .)}
#>    date ind_place ind_work ind_home ind_life ind_friends ind_university
#> 1 23/01       Rio        4       10        5           5             10
#> 2 24/02        LA        6        8        9          11             12
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>